# How to align ChartJS bars to the left?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I want to create a bar chart on ChartJS but I'm not having success when trying to remove this "gap" between the Y-axis 0 bar and the first bar. Is it even possible?

**This is the example with a small gap**
[image: This is the example with a small gap]

**And here is what I want to achieve, without the gap**
[image: And here is what I want to achieve, without the gap]

HTML

```
<canvas id="openedCanvas" height="230" width="680"></canvas>
```

Javascript

```
var data = {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    };
var options = {}

var chart = new Chart($('#openedCanvas'), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

And here's a running Codepen https://codepen.io/fermijs/pen/ZmPRaB

Thank you :)

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: Added @NagaSaiA

Comment: If you remove the all space between the bars then you will get a solution

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result , use scales option for x axis

barPercentage vs categoryPercentage  section of https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html?h=scales

Both of 1.0 will stack together , so adjust according to your requirement

```
scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            categoryPercentage: 0.99,
            barPercentage: 1.0
        }]
    }
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/yGYJKE