# Is there a property in for ChartJS that allows you to align bars to the left?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to create a bar chart with the columns aligned to the left using the PrimeNg p-chart. I started with the stacked graph on http://primefaces.org/primeng/chart/bar.

This is my current graph:

[image]

Desired look:

[image]

I have tried using `categoryPercentage: 0.99,` and `barPercentage: 1.0` from [How to align ChartJS bars to the left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53727089/how-to-align-chartjs-bars-to-the-left). These didn't create my desired look as they expanded the column to the full width. I want to have smaller width columns and shift them over to the left. Are there any properties that can be used to achieve this effect? Are there any alternatives to ChartJS properties?

```
        this.stackedData = 
             [{
                type: 'bar',
                categoryPercentage: 0.25,
                borderRadius: 3,
                label: '200',
                backgroundColor: '#003D79',
                data: [
                    50,
                    55,
                    78,
                    48,
                    90,
                    76,
                    42
                ]
            }, {
                type: 'bar',
                categoryPercentage: 0.25,
                borderRadius: 3,
                label: '400',
                backgroundColor: '#AC0000',
                data: [
                    21,
                    4,
                    24,
                    75,
                    37,
                    65,
                    34
                ]
            }, {
                type: 'bar',
                categoryPercentage: 0.25,
                borderRadius: 3,
                label: '401',
                backgroundColor: '#E80000',
                data: [
                    41,
                    0,
                    24,
                    74,
                    23,
                    21,
                    32
                ]
            }, {
                type: 'bar',
                categoryPercentage: 0.25,

                borderRadius: 3,
                label: '402',
                backgroundColor: '#5C0000',
                data: [
                    41,
                    52,
                    0,
                    74,
                    23,
                    21,
                    32
                ]
            }, {
                type: 'bar',
                categoryPercentage: 0.25,
                borderRadius: 3,
                label: 'Other',
                backgroundColor: '#D5D5D5 ',
                data: [
                ]
            }];


this.stackedOptions = {
            plugins: {
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    intersect: false
                },
                legend: {
                    position: 'bottom',
                    align: 'end',
                    labels: {
                      usePointStyle: 'circle',
                    }
                  },
            },
            scales: {
                x: {
                    stacked: true,
                    grid: {
                        display: false
                     },
                     ticks: {
                        maxRotation: -45,
                        minRotation: -45,
                        padding: 30,

                    }
                },
                y: {
                    stacked: true,
                    grid: {
                        drawBorder: false,
                        lineWidth: 0.5,
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: This looks to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53727089/how-to-align-chartjs-bars-to-the-left. Did that question answer yours?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. That post aligns to the left by increasing the size of the columns and therefore reducing the spacing. I was looking for a way to reduce the size without altering the size of columns